# I need help formatting decimal places in a Text Field using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a few calculations that perform after I select the "Calculate" function.  The results vary depending on the values entered.  I need to limit the results to 2 decimal places.  I have tried numerous options with no luck.  Any help here would be appreciated.  Again, I am using Swift 4 in an iOS app.

Here is a bit of the code I am using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var f0TextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: Any) {
    f0TextField.text = "\(((Double(f1TextField.text ?? "%.2f") ?? 0.0) + (Double(f2TextField.text ?? "%.2f") ?? 0.0))/2)"
```

I have 6 more "textfields" that I have to apply this to also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want final answer in 2 decimal places than you should apply it to final result like below.

```
let currentRatio = Double (rxCurrentTextField.text!)! / Double (txCurrentTextField.text!)!
railRatioLabelField.text! = String(format: "%.2f", currentRatio)
```

Example

```
let myDouble = 3.141
let doubleStr = String(format: "%.2f", myDouble) // "3.14"
```

Comment: Careful with all of those crash operators (`!`).

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @Sebastian, used his suggested code and it works. You can try if it works for you

First have this extension

```
extension Double {
    /// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double {
    let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
    return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
}}
```

then

```
let x = Double(textField.text).rounded(toPlaces: 2)
print(x) // to see if it works
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break up that code. First get the text of the two text fields. Then convert the two text values to `Double`. Then add the two numbers. Then convert the sum to a string formatted as desired.

Here's one way:

```
if let val1 = Double(f1TextField.text ?? "0"), let val2 = Double(f12TextField.text ?? "0") {
    let sum = val1 + val2
    f0TextField.text = String(format: "%.2f", sum)
}
```

But you really should use `NumberFormatter` to show the result in a proper locale sensitive way. And most likely you need it to parse the user entered numbers as well.

You probably should also create a function that takes any two text fields and returns a `String` that you can then set on the appropriate text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try using common Extension for Double

```
extension Double
{
    //MARK: Rounds the double to decimal places value
    /**
     This func return Double to rounded Place
     - paramter places : Number of places to be rounded
     */
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double
    {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Usgae - `Double(newValue).rounded(toPlaces: 0)`